# Selecting common items for price comparison across 2 or more members

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to enable purchase price comparisons across 2 or more members based on the members most recent price paid based on the purchase date.

I have four tables: Member, Items, UOM and Fact

```
Member (membername varchar(50), memberkey int)

Items  (itemname varchar(50), itemkey int)

UOM    (uomname varchar(50), uomkey int)

Fact   (memberkey int, itemkey int, uomkey int, purchaseamount decimal(18,2), quantity int, purchasedate date)
```

My UI allows selection of two or more members to allow comparison of prices per uom.  My result set has to include items where at least two of the selected members have purchased that item and exclude all others.

I set my member list in a temp table by the following:

```
    declare @MemberKeys as varchar(max)
    set @MemberKeys = '702,1382,1389,1390,1391,1392,1393,1394,1395,1396,1397,1401,1402,1404,1405,1406,1516,1844';
    create table #mk (memberName varchar(253), memberkey smallint)

    insert into #mk (memberName, memberkey)
    Select Rownbr + '.)  '  +  membername, memberkey from (
    SELECT
        cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [MemberFacilityName] ASC) as varchar (10)) AS RowNbr
        ,k.value as memberkey
        ,m.memberName

    FROM 
        Member m
        INNER JOIN dbo.String_To_SmallInt_Table(@MemberKeys, ',') AS k
        ON m.Memberkey = k.value            
        ) X
```

Then I use the temp table to filter when querying the fact, uom and item tables.

```
    select m.membername
    ,i.itemname
    ,u.uomname
    ,purchaseamount 
    ,quantity
    ,purchaseamount/quantity as price  
    from Fact f
    join #mk m
    on m.memberkey = f.memberkey
    join Item i
    on i.itemkey = f.itemkey
    join UOM u
    on u.uomkey= f.uomkey
```

Now I need to do the following but need some guidance to accomplish it.

1.) filter out items that are not used by at least two of the select members.

2.) show only the most recent purchase price per member\item\uom based on the purchase date.

3.) order the result set to show member then item for easy comparison (similar to the simplified list below).

```
Member   Item   Price
 mbr1       A   1.11
 mbr2       A   1.12
 mbr3       A   1.52
 mbr4       A   2.01
 mbr1       B   3.01
 mbr2       B   3.03
 mbr3       B   3.12
 mbr4       B   3.41
 mbr1       C   6.01
 mbr2       C   6.63
 mbr3       C   6.92
 mbr4       C   6.99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I implemented this...tell me if my logic is sound:

```
/****Create Sample Data*****/

-->Member table
IF exists (SELECT 1 from dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = 'Member')
DROP TABLE Member
GO

CREATE TABLE Member (membername VARCHAR(50), memberkey INT)
GO 
INSERT INTO Member VALUES
('mbr1',702),
('mbr2',1382),
('mbr3',1389),
('mbr4',1390),
('mbr5',1391),
('mbr6',1392),
('mbr7',1393),
('mbr8',1394),
('mbr9',1395),
('mbr10',1396),
('mbr11',1397),
('mbr12',1401),
('mbr13',1402),
('mbr14',1404),
('mbr15',1405),
('mbr16',1406),
('mbr17',1516),
('mbr18',1111)-->Should NOT show up in query
GO

-->Items table
IF exists (SELECT 1 from dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = 'Items')
DROP TABLE Items
GO

CREATE TABLE Items  (itemname VARCHAR(50), itemkey INT)
GO
INSERT INTO Items VALUES
('A',1),
('B',2),
('C',3),
('D',4)

GO

-->UOM table   
IF exists (SELECT 1 from dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = 'UOM')
DROP TABLE UOM
GO
CREATE TABLE UOM    (uomname VARCHAR(50), uomkey INT)
GO

INSERT INTO UOM  VALUES ('QTY', 1)
GO

-->Fact table
IF exists (SELECT 1 from dbo.sysobjects WHERE name = 'Fact')
DROP TABLE Fact
GO
CREATE TABLE Fact   (memberkey INT, itemkey INT, uomkey INT, purchaseamount      decimal(18,2), quantity INT, purchasedate date)
GO

INSERT INTO Fact VALUES 
(702,  1, 1, 1.11, 2, '1/3/2012'),-->Should show up in query
(1382, 1, 1, 1.12, 3, '1/4/2013'),-->Should NOT show up in query
(1382, 1, 1, 1.14, 2, '7/5/2013'),-->Should show up in query
(1404, 1, 1, 1.21, 2, '1/7/2012'),-->Should show up in query
(1401, 2, 1, 3.01, 1, '4/2/2013'),-->Should NOT show up in query
(1111, 3, 1, 6.92, 1, '12/12/2012'),-->Should NOT show up in query
(702,  3, 1, 5.01, 2, '4/1/2011'),-->Should show up in query
(1401, 3, 1, 4.01, 1, '6/5/2012'),-->Should show up in query
(1397, 4, 1, 5.45, 1, '7/4/2013'),-->Should NOT show up in query
(1397, 4, 1, 5.22, 3, '3/15/2011')-->Should NOT show up in query
GO


/*****Code to get results*****/
BEGIN  

-->Members to Filter On
DECLARE @MemberKeys AS VARCHAR(max)
SET @MemberKeys = '702,1382,1389,1390,1391,1392,1393,1394,1395,1396,1397,1401,1402,1404,1405,1406,1516,1844';


-->Parse out comma delimited VALUES into a table variable
DECLARE @Member TABLE 
(
memberkey INT
)
DECLARE @spot SMALLINT, @str VARCHAR(max), @sql VARCHAR(max)  

WHILE @MemberKeys <> ''  
BEGIN  
    SET @spot = CHARINDEX(',', @MemberKeys)  
    IF @spot>0  
        BEGIN  
            SET @str = LEFT(@MemberKeys, @spot-1) 
            SET @MemberKeys = RIGHT(@MemberKeys, LEN(@MemberKeys)-@spot)  
        END  
    ELSE  
        BEGIN  
            SET @str = @MemberKeys 
            SET @MemberKeys = ''  
        END  
    INSERT INTO @Member VALUES(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@str))   
END  

END;


-->Display Results
WITH staged(memberkey, membername, itemname ,itemkey, uomname, uomkey, purchaseamount, quantity, price, purchasedate, noitems )  
AS
(
SELECT 
 m.memberkey
,m.membername
,i.itemname
,i.itemkey
,u.uomname
,u.uomkey
,f.purchaseamount 
,f.quantity
,f.purchaseamount/f.quantity as price  
,f.purchasedate
,COUNT(m.memberkey) OVER(PARTITION BY i.itemkey )-COUNT(m.memberkey) OVER(PARTITION BY  convert(VARCHAR,m.memberkey)+convert(VARCHAR,i.itemkey) ) as noitems
FROM 
Fact f
    JOIN Member m ON m.memberkey = f.memberkey
    JOIN Items i ON i.itemkey = f.itemkey
    JOIN UOM u ON u.uomkey= f.uomkey
 WHERE 
 EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Member m2 WHERE m.memberkey=m2.memberkey)
 )
 SELECT
      memberkey, 
      membername, 
      itemname ,
          itemkey,
      uomname, 
          uomkey,
      sum(purchaseamount) as purchaseamount , 
      sum(quantity) as quantity , 
      sum(price) as price, 
      max(purchasedate) as purchasedate
 FROM
      staged st
 WHERE
          noitems>0
          and exists(
    select  memberkey, 
            itemkey ,
            uomkey,
            max(purchasedate) as maxdate 
           from staged st2 
                            where st.memberkey=st2.memberkey 
                            and st.itemkey=st2.itemkey 
                            and st.uomkey=st2.uomkey

            group by  
            memberkey, 
            itemkey ,
            uomkey
            having st.purchasedate=max(st2.purchasedate)
            )
 GROUP BY 
          memberkey 
     ,membername  
     ,itemname  
     ,uomname
         , itemkey 
     , uomkey 
 ORDER BY 
         itemname 
         ,memberkey;
```

Comment: Logic is sound - testing on my real tables. I like the use of the cte.  Appears to be working faster than my original solution - thanks! I'll check the io and time stats with larger query but I suspect yours will outperform.

Comment: @user1130761, Took a second look at this and found it summing purchase amount across all records for same item and member. Made a quick change and corrected the logic error. Please see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out on my own but will post my own answer; maybe it could help others with similar tasks.

I was able to complete the three tasks by introducing a second temp table to identify the most recent purchase price per item and member.  Then joining the #mostrecentpurchase temp table to the base table enable effective member price comparisons.

To limit the result set to only items where two or more of the selected members had documented prices, I used the OVER clause and partitioned by item and unit of measure to get a count of members per item/uom.  I then used this count in the where clause to filter out rows where the count was less than one.

Finally, the sorting was accomplished by simple order by clause.  The completed tsql script is below.

```
    declare @MemberKeys as varchar(max)

    set @MemberKeys = '702,1382,1389,1390,1391,1392,1393,1394,1395,1396,1397,1401,1402,1404,1405,1406,1516,1844';

    create table #mk (memberName varchar(253), memberkey smallint)


    insert into #mk (memberName, memberkey)
    Select Rownbr + '.)  '  +  membername, memberkey from (
    SELECT
        cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [MemberFacilityName] ASC) as varchar (10)) AS RowNbr
        ,k.value as memberkey
        ,m.memberName

    FROM 
        Member m
        INNER JOIN dbo.String_To_SmallInt_Table(@MemberKeys, ',') AS k
        ON m.Memberkey = k.value            
        ) X

    create table #mostrecentpurchase(purchasedate date, itemkey int, uomkey int, memberkey int)

    Insert into #mostrecentpurchase(purchasedate, itemkey, uomkey, memberkey)
    select max(f.PurchaseDate) purchasedate
    , f.itemKey
    , f.uomkey
    , f.memberkey
    from  Fact f
    join #mk m
    on m.memberkey = f.memberkey
    group by f.itemkey
    , f.uomkey
    , f.memberkey


    select x.* FROM (
    select m.memberName
    , i.itemname
    , i.itemkey
    , f.purchasedate
    , sum(f.purchaseamount) as purchaseamount
    , sum(f.quantity) as quantity
    , u.uomname
    , sum(f.purchaseamount)/sum(f.quantity) as price 
    , count(m.memberName) OVER(PARTITION BY i.vendorItem_PK,u.UnitOfmeasure) AS mbrCount
    from 
    fact f
    join #mk m
    on m.memberkey = f.memberkey
    join #mostrecentpurchase mrp
    on mrp.purchasedate = f.PurchaseDate
    and mrp.memberkey = f.memberkey
    and mrp.uomkey = f.uomkey
    and mrp.vendoritemkey = f.itemkey
    join item i
    on i.itemkey = f.itemkey
    join uom u
    on u.uomkey = f.uomkey
    group by m.membername,i.itemname,i.itemkey,f.purchasedate,u.uomname
    ) X
    where mbrCount >= @MemberCompCount
    order by X.itemname, X.memberName


    drop table #mk;
    drop table #mostrecentpurchase;
```